# C++ DirectX Having two classes containin functions gives me errors

Tags: c++, directx

I'm creating a fullscreen application and when I add a new class that contains my drawing functions it gives me the following error:

[image: Example]

When I comment out the class It compiles and gives me no errors but when I uncomment it again It starts giving me the same errors again, I have it setup exactly like my other function and it works without problems.

Here is my source:
https://github.com/TheRavenBlue/DirecctX-Fullscreen-Application

I'm quite new to this whole C++ world, but I'm slowly getting there!

Answer (score 0):

In your Window.h file you have variable definitions. Every time you include it the variables get defined. This will cause the errors you see.

You must declare the variables in cpp files for them to work. You may declare them as `extern` in headers if they must be accessible from other code files.

Comment: Okay I tossed them around a bit and it compiled but when I debugg / start the program it crashes: https://gyazo.com/3ada03fe11c20e410234438016bbb860 I have no idea what dies means.

Comment: @RavenHue then you might want to start your C++ journey with something simpler than graphics programming

Comment: Nit: You *declare* variables in headers and *define* them in source files.  Understanding the difference between declarations and definitions is an essential skill in C++ programming.